# Min value of Integer List when it can be empty in scala

Tags: scala, typechecking

I am trying to find min value of integer list also when it can be empty.

```
scala> val minValue:Int = List() match {
     |   case Nil => -1
     |   case xs  => xs.min
     | }
<console>:9: error: diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[B]
starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering
     case xs => xs.min
```

though it worked well not non empty list.

```
scala> val minValue = List(1,2) match {
     |   case Nil => -1
     |   case xs  => xs.min
     | }
minValue: Int = 1
```

How do I find min with out sorting as one way I could think of is sort and get head with getOrElse defaultValue.

Comment: There is no such thing to my knowledge. I assume you mean, I want to return -1 when a list is empty and the min value when it is not.

Comment: I really want to say you should `lift` the `min` function, but I can't figure out how. Anyone know if you can do that somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the typechecker doesn't know what type to use for `List()`. If you specifically annotate the empty list with a type it should work just fine:

```
val minValue:Int = List.empty[Int] match { // ...
```

After discussing with @senia I realized you're probably using -1 as a "hack" to say "no minimum" rather than as an actual value. If that's the case, then using the `Option` type in Scala might be more clear, as you can return the `Some` variant for actual results and the `None` variant in the case of an empty list. Scala sequences actually already have a nice method for doing this for you:

```
scala> List.empty[Int].reduceLeftOption(_ min _)
res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> List(5, 2, 1, 3, 4).reduceLeftOption(_ min _)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Comment: It interesting also what makes him think specifically about `Tuple9` why not `Tuple1` or something else?

Comment: @om-nom-nom - I don't know why the error mentions `Tuple9`. If you do a quick search, it seems like that's what the compiler always comes up with when there's an ambiguous type for an `Ordering`. I'd also be interested to know the reason behind this.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is correct, but you have an incorrect test case: you are using `List[Nothing]` instead of `List[Int]`, try this:

```
List[Int]() match {
  case Nil => -1;
  case xs => xs.min;
}

// -1
```

You could add safe methods to all collections:

```
import scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce

implicit class MinMaxOpt[T](val l: GenTraversableOnce[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def minOpt(implicit o: Ordering[T]) = if (l.isEmpty) None else Some(l.min)
  def minOrElse[T2 >: T](default: T2)(implicit o: Ordering[T]) = minOpt getOrElse default

  def maxOpt(implicit o: Ordering[T]) = if (l.isEmpty) None else Some(l.max)
  def maxOrElse[T2 >: T](default: T2)(implicit o: Ordering[T]) = maxOpt getOrElse default
}

List(1, 2).minOpt
// Some(1)

List[Int]().minOrElse(-1)
// -1
```

Comment: Wouldn't the more idiomatic way be to use `fold` or other higher-order functions?

Comment: @DaoWen: Method that throws an exception instead of optional result doesn't seems right to me.

Comment: I was thinking something more like `xs.fold(-1)(_ min _)`, but now that I think of it the OP's probably using `-1` as a hack to indicate `None`, so I guess you're right.

Comment: @DaoWen: there could be collections with optimized `min`. For instance `BitSet`.

Answer (score 0):

See the full signature of `List.min` in [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List).

```scala
def min[B >: A](implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): A
```

You see, if you use `List()` without any type hint, it will become `List[Nothing]` type, then the compiler cannot find what to use in the place of `cmp`, which must be type of `Ordering[B]` where `B >: Nothing` (`B` is a supertype of `Nothing`. There are too many such type, - `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type - so it cannot determine what to use).